# Imagemagick using metadata properties to mass rename images

Tags: batch-file, command-line, imagemagick, dicom, batch-rename

I have got a ton of dicom files that I want to mass rename using their properties tags.

My question is, what is the syntax for taking a property tag(such as dcm:SeriesNumber) for every image and using it to rename the images in the directory?

I'm guessing it involves breaking it down to the relevant tag using -identify -verbose and then somehow passing that string over to the filename property?

Really would appreciate the help(using win10 command line).

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069). You already asked [Imagemagick using properties to mass rename images](//superuser.com/q/1134440)

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
convert *.dcm -set filename:f "%[dcm:SeriesNumber]"_"%[dcm:AcquisitionNumber]" "%[filename:f].jpg"
```

the **""** after **filename:f** hold the string that's going to represent the file name

[] brackets hold the metadata property, that you can chain by using % percentage sign which declares a new property